# Getting a Fail Trying to Parse a ZonedDateTime from a String Using ZonedDateTimePattern

Tags: nodatime

I've been learning how to use `NodaTime`, as I think it is a far superior "all things temporal" library that the handful of structs in the BCL. Reading the docs and experimenting.

This experiment has me flummoxed. I started out just trying to parse a `ZonedDateTime`.
The things I was trying were not successful, so I thought I'd try something which should be "bulletproof". The following code represents that attempt:

```
Instant thisNow = SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant();
var timezone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Australia/Brisbane"];

var zonedDateTime = thisNow.InZone(timezone);

var zonePattern = ZonedDateTimePattern.GeneralFormatOnlyIso;

var zoneFormatted = zonePattern.Format(zonedDateTime);

var zoneParseResult = zonePattern.Parse(zoneFormatted);

Console.WriteLine(zoneParseResult.Success ? "parse success" : "parse failure");
```

So, simply trying to parse back that which you just converted to a string.

The `zoneFormatted` has the following value `2021-09-04T16:59:08 Australia/Brisbane (+10)`

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

You're using `ZonedDateTimePattern.GeneralFormatOnlyIso`, which is (as the name suggests) only for formatting, not for parsing.

To get a pattern which is able to parse time zones, you need to specify an `IDateTimeZoneProvider`. The easiest way to do that is to start with a format-only pattern, and use `WithZoneProvider`:

```cs
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Text;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pattern = ZonedDateTimePattern.GeneralFormatOnlyIso
            .WithZoneProvider(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
        var text = "2021-09-04T16:59:08 Australia/Brisbane (+10)";
        var result = pattern.Parse(text);
        Console.WriteLine(result.Success);
        Console.WriteLine(result.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: The man himself. It's an honour. Thank you.